# Why text widget shows "no data" but graph shows data?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a metric looking for some data point over 1 day. I created a text widget for it. The dashboard is set show show 1 day as well. The widget shows "no data". But when I edit the widget, it actually shows the right number.

On the dashboard:

[image: Widget in dashboard]

When I edit it:

[image: Widget in Edit mode]

Why is it nos showing 40 on the dashboard?

Comment: The numbers in the dashboard and in the edited widgets seem to never match. The number if the edited widgets are actually correct.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to reproduce this.

On your dashboard, select the 'Actions' dropdown and chose 'View/edit source'. In the json blob, you should notice a `setPeriodToTimeRange` property. It's likely set to false.

If it is, flip it to true and see if it fixes your issue.

Why does this happen? If the time range isn't adjusted, the `singleValue` view cannot display a value that isn't fully aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

For this we need to change the Value type to "Time Range Value"

Steps:

- select your widget.
- go to edit.
- Under Graph option, select your widget type.
- and change Value type from Latest value to which is default selection
  to the "Time range value"

Latest value shows only the latest value and it will not work on the time range basis.